# Update the table to set the word_count column with the number of words in text column separated with a delimiter comma(,)

Tags: sql

Update the table to set the word_count column with the number of words in text column separated with a delimiter comma(,)

Columns

```
ID  TEXT                         WORD_COUNT EMAIL                      DOMAIN    AGE
--- ---------------------------- ---------- ------------------------- ---------- ----
1   word1,word2,word3                     3 abc@gmail.com               gmail    10
2   word1,word2                             abc@yahoo.com                        23
3   word1,word2,word3,word4                 abc@gmail.com                        1A
4   word1                                   abc@hello.com                        2A
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try to do homework by yourself! Otherwise you will never learn how to write the easiest statements by your own

Comment: Select id,length(text)-length(replace(text, ',', ''))+1 word_count from aptroid; I am getting error while updating                                               update aptroid
 set word_count=(select length(text)-length(replace(text, ',', ''))+1 from aptroid) ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the subquery:

```
update aptroid
    set word_count = length(text)-length(replace(text, ',', ''))+1
```

Comment: Gordon isn't there a better way to count a character?